# Go's Disadvantage

Tags: go

I've been learning Go for a while and found that it has a lot of good features (simple and clean syntax, fast compilation/execution, good support for concurrency, first class functions, etc). But very few popular projects are developed in Go.

I'm just wondering what are the main disadvantages that restricts Go from becoming a mainstream language? Can someone come up with a kind of program/project for which Go is obviously not suitable to be used?

Comment: Regardless of programming language you can always find some program that is better-suited to be written in a different language. I'm a bit unclear as to what you're actually trying to ask here.

Comment: If you're asking "Why isn't Go more popular if it's such a great language?" ... well, "best" doesn't always win :)  IMHO...

Comment: What I meant is， does go has some critical limitations (that is not easy to be noticed)? Sorry for the unclear expression (I'm not native in English). Thanks anyway for commenting :)

Comment: An update from 2014: Docker has become the next big thing for cloud computing, and even Microsoft announced support for it. It's written in Go. Many of the tools/technologies around docker (like CoreOS) also make heavy use of Go. It's an awesome language, it's just that the adoption of language is slow at first (it's a fan-out function).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go is only 3 years old. C is more than 40 years old. C++ more than 30. Perl 25. Ruby almost 20. Java is a relatively young language at 17, and C# quite young at 10 (or 12, depending on how you count it). And Java and C# had a lot of resources thrown at making them dominant, with Sun and Microsoft investing in all kinds of tools and libraries and getting people trained in them. Compared to that, 3 years is almost nothing. Google spends some money on developers for Go, but at nowhere near the scale of C# and Java. And 3 years isn't a lot of time for really prominent products to be written and released in Go.

Give it a few years. Write some code in Go. Maybe yours will become the next prominent project.

As far as what it's not suited for, it's not suited for anything that requires a really mature language and toolset. If you want fancy refactoring IDEs, tons of off the shelf libraries, and lots of tutorials and information online, you probably won't find that yet. The last I checked, its garbage collector was a little weak; it's possible to get leaks due to mistaking integers for pointers, since it's a conservative collector. This could be fixed by now, but its indicative of the relative immaturity of the Go implementation; there are certain things that may be solved problems in other languages (or have well-known workaround patterns), which are still a bit up in the air for Go.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the GC bug only presented itself on 32-bit systems and I believe it has been fixed.

Comment: @Tom There are still open issues about this ([353](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=353) and [909](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=909)), which have been recently updated, so I'm pretty sure the problem still exists. And a conservative collector still has this weakness on a 64 bit machine, it's just much less likely to come up as you have a smaller chance of accidentally pinning any given pointer.

Comment: The GC bug isn't a big deal. I ran into a problem with it, but it only caused problems after 12 or so hours of constant running (this on an ARM board with < 100 mb ram). It's because they used a conservative GC, which was done to get the language to 1.0 status. It's not enough to deter from using the language, and it'll likely be fixed by early next year.

Comment: @tjameson The question was about disadvantages. The conservative GC is a disadvantage; it does affect some programs, especially programs which involve manipulating lots of large numbers as well as lots of pointers, and long-running programs. By the way, the amount of RAM isn't the issue, it's the size, and layout, of the address space that matters. I'm not saying this is a killer weakness, or that it won't be fixed; but it's an example of the relative immaturity of Go, compared to languages like Java which have had years of work and research poured into their GC.

Comment: @BrianCampbell - The amount of RAM is an issue. 100MB will fill up sooner than 4GB given the same application. I just wanted to show a real-world example where it was a problem, because of the limited  memory. The application dealt with binary data, which caused it to get pinned. For 99% of applications, the GC is good enough, especially on x64, so I don't consider it a significant disadvantage. The slowness of the GC is a bigger deal however.

Comment: @tjameson OK, sure, the leak will effect you faster on 100 MB of ram than 4 GB. And 12 hours isn't a lot of runtime; lots of applications need processes to run longer than that without interruption. Anyhow, I'm really not trying to argue that this is a killer weakness. Just that it is a weakness, for some applications, which is what the question was asking about. The main point of my answer is that the main reason that Go doesn't have a lot of prominent programs written in it is time, not any inherent disadvantage.

Comment: Most of the information in this post are irrelevant now.